# spring hibernate Async task issue No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, completable-future

This is my method to save data . It is working fine

```
    public Future<SocialLogin> loginUserSocial(Social model) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(model);
        SocialLogin dto = new SocialLogin();
        dto.setUser_id(model.getUser_id());
        return new AsyncResult<SocialLogin>(dto);
    }
```

But if I put `@Async` annotion on method
I've got the following exception.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

If anyone have knowledge about this exception, I appreciate.
thanks

Comment: Please post your Bean containing the Future<..> definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html)

> It is not intended that implementors be threadsafe. Instead each thread/transaction should obtain its own instance from a SessionFactory.

According to documentation threads should have their own sessions. If you get session by `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` you'll get null because its' access protected by ThreadLocals.

You can create new session for per thread by this code.

```
@Async
public Future<SocialLogin> loginUserSocial(Social model) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(model);
        SocialLogin dto = new SocialLogin();
        dto.setUser_id(model.getUser_id());
        return new AsyncResult<SocialLogin>(dto);
    }
```